# What is the double opposite of Schadenfreude?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

If schadenfreude means "pleasure derived by someone from another person's misfortune", is there a word to call someone who **can't** feel happy when something good/exciting happens to a relative/friend/someone close?

Comment: _Fradenscheude_?

Comment: @medica That question is asking for a different "opposite".

Comment: Indeed, that is not a valid duplicate.

Comment: That is not a duplicate! This question wants a word for someone who is *un*happy about someone else's success, while that one wants a word for someone who is *happy* about someone else's success. Completely different animals.

Comment: The linked duplicate is wrong, but [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486636/what-is-the-inverse-of-schaedenfreude?noredirect=1&lq=1) looks like a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *gluckschmerz* in German means "displeasure due to another person's success" which is essentially the opposite of *schadenfreude* (which is also originally from German).  [This page](http://progressivemirror.blogspot.ca/2011/04/schadenfreude-and-gluckschmerz.html) discusses both terms.

Comment: Links only are not sufficient as answers; copying selected passages is more helpful, because links can be lost.

Comment: @medica The linked article was added for additional information.  The text of my answer gives all of the information requested in the question.

Comment: @user75110 If this answers your question, can you accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it?

Comment: Yes, but is *gluckschmerz* a term that is used in *English*? This is ELU after all.