# What is the inverse of schaedenfreude?

Tags: germanic-languages

If schadenfreude is pleasure from another’s misery, what is displeasure caused by another’s success.

Comment: I would probably call it "resentment", though it is a word used in multiple senses.

Comment: Have you considered using Jealousy?

Comment: no research. no vote

Comment: _Schadenfreude_, spelled that way, is a German noun and is always capitalized. You probably shouldn't use it in writing unless you can spell it correctly all the time. You should also be able to pronounce it correctly, even if you're speaking English; that's the price one pays for using foreign words while they're still recognized as foreign.

Answer (score 1):

> what is displeasure caused by another’s success.

Why **envy** of course:

> A feeling of discontent and resentment aroused by and in conjunction with desire for the possessions or qualities of another.
>   *[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/envy)*

> a feeling of resentful discontent, begrudging admiration, or covetousness with regard to another's advantages, possessions, or attainments; desire for something possessed by another.
>   *[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/envy)*

---

Cf. **jealousness**:

> Traditional usage holds that we are jealous when we fear losing something that is important to us and envious when we desire that which someone else has. In this view, one might experience jealousy upon seeing one's spouse flirt with another (because of the fear of losing the spouse), while one might experience envy upon seeing a friend with an attractive date (because of one's desire to have an attractive date of one's own). In common usage, this distinction is not always observed, and jealousy and jealous are often used in situations that involve envy. ...
>   *[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jealous)*

Answer (score 0):

"Displeasure caused by another's success" sounds a lot like envy to me.
According to the Oxford English Dictionary (online):

"A feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else's possessions, qualities, or luck."